# locking a case after action? is this possible?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, switch-statement

Let's say I have my code like this:

```
switch ( value ) {

case 1 "Hello" // <--- whatever word is in here is a command to make the following happen:

name.systemtext("Good job!"); // display this in the console

case 2 "hi"
name.systemtext("A good job also!");

case 3 "bye"
name.systemtext("many great jobs were had");
```

I want to prevent these to be repeatable.

So if someone is at case 2, I don't want the user to be able to repeat `hello` or `hi` once the action "good job" has been displayed. Instead I'd want to display a message that the input has already been typed and then force the person to go for the only case left, which is 3 ("bye").

I tried to make this as clear as possible so I hope someone can help. I'm going to guess someone will tell me that to achieve this I'll need to use something other than `switch`? I'm fine with that but I'm just curious about whether this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
private List<string> _possibleCases = new List<string>{"Hello", "Hi", ...};
...

var valueToCheck = "Hi";
var foundCase = this._possibleCases.FirstOrDefault(x => x == valueToCheck);

if (foundCase != null) this._possibleCases.Remove(foundCase);

switch (foundCase)
{
    case "Hello":
        // ...
        break;
    case "Hi":
        // ...
        break;
    ...
    default:
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: I see where youre going with this but Its not liking it when im trying to implement it:    public string foundcase = this._possibleCases.FirstOrDefault("text"); this. seems to unavailable in context

Comment: You don't even need the `switch`, just make the list a dictionary and store the `Action<>` with the string then just directly call it.

Comment: I'm not near VS, so it might need to be `FirstOrDefault(x => x == valueToCheck)`. Intellisense is life.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a state machine.

You don't need a switch and the machine approach allows you to change the internal logic of the machine while the input loop matching into the machine would not need to change much.

First, I'll show just the input loop matching into the machine, to show how simple it looks.  After that, I'll show the whole program, which makes it seem much more complicated, but remember that using the machine makes it very simple for the consumer of the machine.

```
var machine = new StateMachine();

while (!machine.IsFinished())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input a number from 1 to 3, but don't repeat a number you've input previously");
    var input = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (validInput.Contains(input.KeyChar)) {

        var newState = machine.TryTransition(input.KeyChar.ToString());

        if (newState == machine.Forbidden) {
            Console.WriteLine("You've input that before, try again!");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(newState.StateOutput);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Below is the whole program including the details of the machine.  In this case, I chose to use a `static` that is "shared" by each state to implement the idea of tracking over time whether a state has ever been visited the one allowed time.

Another approach, if your logic is not wanting to only allow a state once, would be to actually move the allowed states into each individual state, where each individual state might only allow transitions to certain other states, but not all of them ( a common state machine case).

In this case, though, it seemed like tracking the remaining allowed states, in a static accessible to every state made things simple.   You could certainly get rid of the static (statics have their problems) and move the concept of tracking the remaining allowable states into the `StateMachine` class itself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StateMachineConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public abstract class AbstractState
        {
            static protected Dictionary<string,AbstractState> valuesToStates = new Dictionary<string,AbstractState>();

            protected static List<AbstractState> allowedTransitions = new List<AbstractState>();

            public string StateValue { get; set; }
            public string StateOutput { get; set; }

            protected void RegisterState(AbstractState state, string stateValue, string stateOutput)
            {
                stateValue = stateValue.ToLower();
                AddStateToAllowedList(state);
                AbstractState.valuesToStates.Add(stateValue, state);
                StateOutput = stateOutput;
            }

            protected void AddStateToAllowedList(AbstractState stateToAdd)
            {
                if (AbstractState.allowedTransitions.Contains(stateToAdd))
                {
                    throw new Exception("cannot add state to the allowed list more than once.");
                }
                AbstractState.allowedTransitions.Add(stateToAdd);

            }

            public AbstractState DoTransition(string stateToTransitionTo)
            {
                String stateValueKey = stateToTransitionTo.ToLower();
                if (!AbstractState.valuesToStates.ContainsKey(stateValueKey))
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("{0} does not exist",stateValueKey));
                }

                AbstractState stateToCheckFor = AbstractState.valuesToStates[stateValueKey];

                if (AbstractState.allowedTransitions.Exists(item => item.GetHashCode() == stateToCheckFor.GetHashCode()))
                {
                    AbstractState.allowedTransitions.Remove(stateToCheckFor);
                    return stateToCheckFor;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }

            public int CountAllowedStatesRemaining()
            {
                return allowedTransitions.Count;
            }
        }

        public class StartState : AbstractState
        {
            public StartState() { StateValue = "0"; StateOutput = ""; }
        }

        public class HiState : AbstractState
        {
            public HiState()
            {
                RegisterState(this, "2", "A good job also!");
            }
        }

        public class HelloState : AbstractState
        {
            public HelloState()
            {
                RegisterState(this, "1","Good job!");
            }
        }

        public class ByeState : AbstractState
        {
            public ByeState()
            {
                RegisterState(this, "3","many great jobs were had");
            }
        }

        public class ForbiddenState : AbstractState
        {
            public ForbiddenState()
            {
                StateValue = "-1"; StateOutput = "";
            }
        }

        public class StateMachine
        {
            private AbstractState _currentState = new StartState();
            private ForbiddenState _forbidden = new ForbiddenState();

            public ForbiddenState Forbidden { get { return _forbidden; } }
            public AbstractState CurrentState { get { return _currentState;  } }
            public AbstractState TryTransition(string stateValue)
            {
                AbstractState nextState = _currentState.DoTransition(stateValue);
                if (nextState != null) {
                    _currentState = nextState;
                    return CurrentState;
                } else {
                    return Forbidden;
                }
            }

            public StateMachine()
            {
                var hello = new HelloState();
                var hi = new HiState();
                var bye = new ByeState();
            }

            public bool IsFinished()
            {
                return CurrentState.CountAllowedStatesRemaining() == 0;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Char> validInput = new List<Char>();
            validInput.Add('1');
            validInput.Add('2');
            validInput.Add('3');

            var machine = new StateMachine();

            while (!machine.IsFinished())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input a number from 1 to 3, but don't repeat a number you've input previously");
                var input = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();

                if (validInput.Contains(input.KeyChar)) {

                    var newState = machine.TryTransition(input.KeyChar.ToString());

                    if (newState == machine.Forbidden) {
                        Console.WriteLine("You've input that before, try again!");
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine(newState.StateOutput);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit program");
            var discard = Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I repasted the full code, since I somehow accidentally pasted an earlier version that did not use a "Forbidden" state.

Comment: Hey DWright this seems to be just what I was looking to do, thank you so very much for taking the time to help me out with possible examples of how I could achieve my goal, I'm going to be toying with this today and see if I get it to work how I want!

Comment: I tried toying with this but as a beginner I cant wrap my head around this at all yet unfortunately haha

Comment: Gotcha, well let me know if I can help with an explanation or something.